# is it possible to decompose nonperiodic sinusoidal signal?

Tags: analysis, fourier-series, transformation

Using Fourier series we can decompose any any signal into it's elementary signals but condition is that signal should be periodic and sinusoidal one.

Now, is it possible to decompose nonperiodic sinusoidal signal with Fourier analysis or any other method? If yes, how and if no, why?

Comment: Absolutely, using all frequencies, not just harmonics. This yields the well-known Fourier transform (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. A [Fourier series](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) is periodical by definition, because a Fourier series is the sum of periodical functions having a same period.

There is another concept which is [Fourier transform](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) where the functions "to be transformed" are not supposed to be periodical.

Comment: I added some details in the post as well as links to Wikipedia in order for you to have further details.